# How add PHP code to my countdown javascript code for add data to MySQL column automatically after countdown finished?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my countdown javascript code everyday on 23:00 of local time will finish and after 1 hour again will start to countdown for tomorrow and this continues. I wanted to know is it possible to add PHP code to this till after countdown finished everyday It adds "5" to my "Credit" column ("Credit" + 5 ) in my MySQL automatically ? appreciate for any kind of guidance.

```
<script>

    var countDown = (function() {
      var startStream;
      var endStream;
      var streamingText = 'Your match started!';
      var updateElement;

      // Pad single digit numbers
      function pad(n) {
        return (n<10?'0':'') + +n;
      }

      // Format a time difference as hh:mm:ss
      // d0 and d1 are date objects, d0 < d1
      function timeDiff(d0, d1) {
        var diff = d1 - d0;
        return pad(diff/3.6e6|0) + ':' + pad((diff%3.6e6)/6e4|0) + ':' + pad(diff%6e4/1000|0);
      }

      // start, end are UNIX UTC time values in seconds for the start and end of streaming
      return function(elementId, start, end) {
        var now = new Date();
        var returnValue;

        // By default, run again just after next full second
        var delay = 1020 - now.getMilliseconds();

        // turn start and end times into local Date objects
        if (start) startStream = new Date(start*1000);
        if (end) endStream = new Date(end*1000);

          // If now is after endStream, add 1 day,
          // Use UTC to avoid daylight saving adjustments
          if (now > endStream) {
            endStream.setUTCHours(endStream.getUTCHours() + 24);
            startStream.setUTCHours(startStream.getUTCHours() + 24);
          }

        // Store the element to write the text to
        if (elementId) updateElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

        // If it's streaming time, return streaming text
        if (now >= startStream && now < endStream) {
          returnValue = streamingText;

          // Run again after streaming end time
          delay = endStream - now;

        } else {
          // Otherwise, count down to startStream
          returnValue = timeDiff(now, startStream);
        }

        // Write the time left or streaming text
        updateElement.innerHTML = returnValue;

        // Call again when appropriate
        setTimeout(countDown, delay);
      };
    }());


    // Testing code

    // Create dates for a local time of 21:00 today
    var myStart = new Date();
    myStart.setHours(23,0,0,0);
    var myEnd = new Date()
    myEnd.setHours(24,0,0,0);

    // Create UNIX time values for same time as UTC
    var startUTCTimeValue = myStart/1000|0
    var endUTCTimeValue   = myEnd/1000|0

    // Run when page loads
    window.onload = function() {
      countDown('foo', startUTCTimeValue, endUTCTimeValue);
    }

    </script>
    <font face="Trebuchet MS">
    <div id="foo" style="color: white; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"></div>
```

Comment: look to using ajax

Comment: Take a delve into [jQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ... makes it a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: @IncredibleHat which part of my code should I add this jquery.ajax ? I'm amateur in jquery.ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Ajax is the way to go here i guess.

It seems like you are very new and might not know what ajax is.

In short with Ajax you can call a webpage url in the background. So You could call www.yourdomain.com/addCredits.php

It will do the same as if you would visit that url in your browser. Just write your SQL Code inside that addCredits.php File and you're done.

Just add something like this to your javascript:

```
$.ajax({url: "addCredits.php"});
```

You will have to embed jquery inside your document first though.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And also you might want to wait for that script to load before you call that function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({url: "addCredits.php"});
});
```

Edit:

Your Counter acutally seems to continue in a loop since it keeps up calling itself in the end.

But i would say just put it where your setTimeout is at the end of your function.

Edit2:

Here is an Example with a Clock, your code seems to be over-complicated to be honest. It doesn't really work when i put it in a fiddle aswell...

You could just use this instead:

```js
function startTime() {

    // set time variables h=hour, m=minute, s=second
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    
    //check if 0's have to be added for better appearance. no logical use!
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    //display current time on the element with id="txt"
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
    //check if its 23:00:00 ... if so call addCredits.php
   if(h == 23 && m == 00 && s == 00) {
    $.ajax({url: "addCredits.php"});
    }
    
    //restart this function every second to update the clock
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , I could understand now :) @ChristophDietrich

Comment: If I want for example this url {url: "addCredits.php"} open once If the countdown timer finished how will be ?

Comment: I written my sql code in {url: "addCredits.php"} , just now the problem is i don't know where i should use ajax in my javascript code

Comment: I tried your ajax code after `// Call again when appropriate
        setTimeout(countDown, delay);
      };
    }());` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't need any condition ?! Because we want after countdown finished just 1 time do this "Credit" +5 not more.

Comment: on this url everytime become reload the sessions will get Credit. {url: "addCredits.php"}

Comment: Thanks a lot bro , just one question , This code of you whenever become 23:00 local time this url will work : {url: "addCredits.php"} , true ?

Comment: Yes. Just modify this part:  if(h == 23 && m == 00 && s == 00) to test it. If you want it to call at 21:15 and 12 seconds you would do if(h == 21 && m == 15 && s == 12)  I have to admint this isn't really a good way to do it, however for a beginner its easier to learn this way ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your help bro , God bless you <3

Comment: I tested your code on my web page now but after 23:00 didn't add any Credit !

Comment: whats the problem?!